# Is this by reference or by value?

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference

I have very little experience writing C# code, but I want to make a robust Windows GUI for some of my code. I was wondering if the following code was pass by value or by reference. Specifically if `bytes[]` is copied before it is passed to mystery? Do I need an explicate ref statement in the extern?

```
 [DllImport("unSHA.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
 private static extern void time(byte[] bytes);
```

Comment: By reference. All arrays are reference types in .NET.

Comment: @leppie: No, it's passed by value.

Comment: Is this really a good question? The only part (arguably) useful to anyone else is the bit about arrays being passed by reference or value... which does not form any part of the title and is hidden away in the body. Even then, it should most likely be closed as duplicate anyway

Comment: @Guffa: You are splitting hairs. ;p 'Call by XXX' implies the 'XXX is copied'.

Comment: @leppie: Passing by reference doesn't imply that the reference is copied. The term "passing by XXX" is used for the way that the parameter is passed, if you use it to specify whether the variable passed is a value type or referencec type, you are only adding to the confusion. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parameters are always passed by value, unless you use the `ref` or `out` keyword.

An array is a reference type, so the value that is passed is a copy of the reference to the array.

Comment: So, the pointer is a copy and if I mess up the pointer the change won't be seen by the caller?

Comment: A change to the POINTER - but a change to the VALUE in the array will be seen.

Comment: @Mikhail: Yes, the method can do whatever it likes with the value, it's not put back in the variable `bytes`. Any changes to the array itself will of course take effect.

Answer (score 1):

The bytes parameter is passed by reference which is true for all array types in .NET.